# Prove that a group G is finitely generated if and only if there is a surjective homomorphism $F(\{1,..,n \}) \to G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This if from Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0. There is an another definition of subgroup generated by a  subset. Here it is:

> Let $G$ be a group and $A$ its subset. By universal property of a free group we have a homomorphism $\phi_a:F(A) \to G$ such that $\phi_a(a)=a$. Then its image is the subgroup generated by $A$ in $G$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Well, I know that group $G$ is finitely generated if and only if there is a surjective homomorphism $\phi_A: F(A) \to G, \phi_A(a)=a$ for some finite subset $A \subseteq G$.

Comment: The key difference is that it's not ANY surjective homomorphism, it's THE surjective homomorphism $\phi_A: F(A) \to G$ such that $\phi_A(a) = a$ for all $a \in A$.

Comment: I don't understand, are you looking for a solution to your problem or do you want an hint?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa anything that can help.

Comment: @Jxt921 Ok. I wanted to give an hint.... but unfortunately I couldn't find any so I provided a solution. The point is that it seems quite straightforward once you know the properties of homomorphisms and the concrete characterization of free groups......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view this is intuitively obvious. But I don't know how much "multiplication mechanics" in free and other groups can be taken for granted.

Assume that the group $G$ is generated by its elements $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$. The free group $F_n:=F\bigl([n]\bigr)$ contains the special elements $k$, $1\leq k\leq n$. It is the essence of free generators that the map $$\phi:\quad [n]\to G,\qquad k\mapsto a_k$$
can be extended to a homomorphism $\tilde\phi: F_n\to G$, which is  surjective since the $a_k$ generate $G$.

Similarly, assume that $\phi:F_n\to G$ is a surjective homomorphism. If $$a_k:=\phi(k)\in G$$
are the images of the free generators of $F_n$ then they will generate $G$, because each $x\in G$ is the image of a power product in the generators $k$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove that $\text{Im } \phi_A$, the image of the homomorphism $\phi_A$, is exactly $A$.

One way to prove that is to prove the inclusions
$$A \subseteq \text{Im }\phi_A \text{ and } \text{Im } \phi_A \subseteq A\ .$$

The first inclusion is quite trivial since by hypothesis for every $a \in A \subseteq G$ you have that $a=\phi_A(a) \in \text{Im }\phi_A$, so $A \subseteq \text{Im } \phi_A$.

To prove the other inclusion one simply has to remind that every element of $F(A)$ is (almost) a finite string $(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ of elements of $A$ and that composition in $F(A)$ is given by concatenation.
From this and the fact that $\phi_A$ is an homomorphism it follows that
$$\phi_A((a_1,\dots,a_k))=\phi_A((a_1)\cdots(a_k))=\phi_A((a_1))\cdots\phi_A((a_k))=a_1\dots a_k$$
so every element in the image of $\phi_A$ is a product of elements of $A$, hence it must belong to $A$ itself.

This proves that $\text{Im }\phi_A \subseteq A$, hence the thesis.